# Database connection error, after CLI install?

Tags: magento2, database, installation, php-7.2, centos

First time Magento user here, seeking enlightenment. I did a CLI install on CentOS 7 using the following command...

```
./bin/magento setup:install 
 --base-url="http://example.com/shop/"
 --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name="th_magento"
 --db-user="th_magento" --db-password="asdfashd238"
 --admin-firstname="Hugh" --admin-lastname="Mongous"
 --admin-email="humongous@example.com" --admin-user="admin"
 --admin-password="b39fe8a09" --backend-frontname="aaa"

[... ssh buffer too small ...]

Module 'Magento_WebapiAsync':
[Progress: 818 / 833]
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
[Progress: 819 / 833]
Module 'Magento_Weee':
[Progress: 820 / 833]
Module 'Magento_WeeeGraphQl':
[Progress: 821 / 833]
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
[Progress: 822 / 833]
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
[Progress: 823 / 833]
Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
[Progress: 824 / 833]
Module 'Magento_WishlistGraphQl':
[Progress: 825 / 833]
Module 'Temando_Shipping':
[Progress: 826 / 833]
Module 'Vertex_Tax':
[Progress: 827 / 833]
[Progress: 828 / 833]
Installing admin user...
[Progress: 829 / 833]
Caches clearing:
Cache cleared successfully
[Progress: 830 / 833]
Disabling Maintenance Mode:
[Progress: 831 / 833]
Post installation file permissions check...
For security, remove write permissions from these directories: '/home/example/public_html/shop/app/etc'
[Progress: 832 / 833]
Write installation date...
[Progress: 833 / 833]
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /aaa
Nothing to import.
```

For some reason I can't understand<sup>1</sup> all I get when I navigate to `/aaa` is an `Error while establishing database connection` message (rough translation, locale is not english).

I tried some basic troubleshooting like checking requirements with the web based install, and ensuring that I can login using the MySQL client and it works. I can't find the logs for the error, tough...

I can post additional data if needed. It might be worth noting the SQL server is  MariaDB 10.0 and that the frontend shows no errors (it seems to display correctly).

---

1: Wouldn't the install stop *before* the `[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.` if there was a problem?

---

#### Update: env.php

The db user and password match...

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'th_magento',
                'username' => 'th_magento',
                'password' => 'asdfashd238',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

While at it I also enabled developer mode, but nothing changed in the error page html. The `var/log/debug.log` file contains only  `cache_invalidate` entries, while `connector.log` is empty.

Comment: add you your app/etc/env.php databse conneciton array code after installation.

Comment: your database is down

Comment: @MagenX how can it be down if the install used the db and CLI `mysql` login is ok?

Comment: @SaphalJha I updated with the env.php's db section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
php bin/magento setup:install 
     --base-url="http://example.com/shop/"
     --db-host="127.0.0.1" 
     --db-name="th_magento"
     --db-user="th_magento" 
     --db-password="asdfashd238"
     --admin-firstname="Hugh" 
     --admin-lastname="Mongous"
     --admin-email="humongous@example.com" 
     --admin-user="admin"
     --admin-password="b39fe8a09" 
     --backend-frontname="aaa"
     --language="en_US"
     --currency="USD"
     --timezone="America/Chicago"
     --use-rewrites=1
```

Comment: This and replacing all FollowSymlinks directives with SymlinkIfOwnwner match did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching from localhost to 127.0.0.1 or vice versa for your database host in the magento configuration.  Failing that you might have to put the FQDN to the database server.

Comment: do i need to drop the tables or just re-run the install command ?

Comment: Edit `app/etc/env.php` on server.  If it works and you get connection and redirect you will need to update base urls in db as shown in other answer.

Comment: Same error with 127.0.0.1, localhost, and FQDN, I also updated the question...